# Can't access to Sonar or project doesn't exist on Sonar instance

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

We are setting up Sonar for a particular project for the first time and we are getting the below error.

I am just wondering why are sonar is trying to retrieve information from the project as this is the first time SONAR is set up for this project

```
[INFO] Building <project1> Application
[INFO]    task-segment: [org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.pdf-report:maven-pdfreport-plugin:1.3:generate] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [pdfreport:generate {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Team workbook report type selected
[INFO] Retrieving project info for <project1>
[ERROR] Can�t access to Sonar or project doesn't exist on Sonar instance. HTTP KO to     http://sonar.server.com:8080/sonar/api/resources?resource=<project1>&depth=0&format=xml
java.io.IOException: Can�t access to Sonar or project doesn't exist on Sonar instance.
at org.sonar.report.pdf.util.SonarAccess.getUrlAsDocument(SonarAccess.java:132)
at org.sonar.report.pdf.entity.Project.initializeProject(Project.java:98)
at org.sonar.report.pdf.PDFReporter.getProject(PDFReporter.java:114)
at org.sonar.report.pdf.PDFReporter.getReport(PDFReporter.java:71)
at org.sonar.report.pdf.mojo.SonarPDFMojo.execute(SonarPDFMojo.java:162)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
[INFO] [01:22:06.415] Execute org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.pdf-report:maven-pdfreport-plugin:1.3:generate done: 615 ms
```

And also i do not think the problem is with maven-pdfreport-plugin because the other projects which are already using sonar are running without any error.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

We have the same problem and resolved it by adding some credentials. Tested on Sonar 3.7 and Sonar PDF Plugin 1.3

In eclipse put this as your maven Goals:

```
org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.pdf-report:maven-pdfreport-plugin:1.3:generate -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dreport.type=executive -Dsonar.pdf.username=admin -Dsonar.pdf.password=admin
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing `sonar.pdf.username` and `sonar.pdf.password` does the trick for me as well.

```
-Dsonar.pdf.username=[Sonar instance User name] -Dsonar.pdf.password=[Sonar instance  Password]
```

---

```
org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.pdf-report:maven-pdfreport-plugin:1.3:generate -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dreport.type=executive -Dsonar.pdf.username=admin -Dsonar.pdf.password=admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the limitation of the PDF Report Plugin.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-1510

Give it a try after removing this plugin. It should be back to normal.

Comment: Thanks! But the other projects in this same instances are running perfectly.

Comment: which version of the plug-in you are using? is it PDF-REPORT-1.3.1

Comment: Kindly update the PDF Report plugin jar in SonarQube to 1.3.1. check this reference : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PDF+Plugin

Comment: Thanks Again Ahsan. I skipped PDF tests using `-Dsonar.pdf.skip=true` and the build was successful but the project is not getting created in SONAR. This have anything to do with the PDF report!!? :(

Answer (score 0):

The PDF Report plugin runs always, even in the first analysis, so 
that's the reason. It should work in the first analysis since it is a 
PostJob extension. 
Your problem is probably caused by one of this reasons: 
 - The current version of PDF Report is not currently compatible with Sonar 3.6. 
 - Your project is protected with username and password, if so, you 
can configure it in the project configuration (on Sonar UI) : use this command :

```
-Dsonar.forceAuthentication=true -Dsonar.pdf.username=myusername -Dsonar.pdf.password=mypassword
```

Regards, 
Youssef